# How can I connect my Shopify app's Theme extension with stores using Shopify CLI and PHP?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-cli, shopify-app-extension

**How to create and use Shopify theme extension for Shopify Apps with PHP?**

I have created a Shopify app and I want to use a Theme extension instead of a script tag. I create theme extensions using Shopify CLI. now I want to connect it with stores.

[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh7gU.png)

[This is the screenshot of the folder that I created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwJg.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                                                                                                                     Put a line of code in your extension block, push to your development store. Now enable previews in your App by clicking the link the CLI gives you, and then visit the store, theme, customizer. Now you can test if your extension loaded by enabling it in the customizer and seeing the code from your block, in the theme, where you put it.
```

It is pretty easy to do. Shopify has ironed out most of the kinks, so I find it takes very few keystrokes to go from typing in my code editor, using the CLI and seeing the result live in a theme.

I suggest you play and follow the Shopify recipes to get to this point.

Comment: In Shopify recipes, there are points that how we can create the extension...I want to know after creation how can I connect the extension with the theme app?

Comment: You have to define better what you want. Without a more detailed explanation of what you want to do, I suspect no one can or will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your app settings from the Shopify partner account, you will find the settings for extensions. There you will see to Enable/Disable theme app extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).